# how to add a newly created node to linklist?

Tags: c, linked-list

here is my code, i can only add the node to the head of the linklist, but how to append to the tail to the linklist? thanks

```
struct recordNode {
  char name[256];  
  char event[128];  /
  float time;
  struct recordNode* next;
};

struct recordNode* temp;
struct recordNode* aRecordPointer = NULL;

struct recordNode* createRecord(char* name, char* event, float time) { 

  temp = (struct recordNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct recordNode));
  strcpy(temp->name, name);
  strcpy(temp->event, event);
  temp->time = time;

  /* link up */
  if (aRecordPointer == NULL) {
     aRecordPointer = temp;
     temp->next = NULL;
  } else {
     temp->next = aRecordPointer;
     aRecordPointer = temp;
  }

  return  aRecordPointer;

}

int main() {

  struct recordNode* record = createRecord("1abc", "abc", 12.25);
  record = createRecord("2abc", "abc", 25.98);
  record = createRecord("3abc", "abc", 52.60);  

}

/* now result:

   3abc abc 12.25
   2abc abc 25.98
   1abc abc 52.60

   needed result:

   1abc abc 52.6
   2abc abc 25.98
   3abc abc 12.25

*/
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Note that in C, the preferred usage of `malloc` is as follows: `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp))`.  Note no cast, and the `sizeof` is invoked on `*temp`, so that if the type ever changes, this will automatically still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that aRecordPointer is your pointer to the head (first) element of list, you need to iterate the list from head to tail (last).

```
struct recordNode* createRecord(char* name, char* event, float time){ 
  temp = (struct recordNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct recordNode));
  strcpy(temp->name, name);
  strcpy(temp->event, event);
  temp->time = time;
  temp->next = NULL;

  if (aRecordPointer == NULL) {
     aRecordPointer = temp;
  }
  else {
    struct recordNode* pLast = aRecordPointer;

    /* find the last element */
    while(pLast->next != NULL) {
      pLast = pLast->next;
    }

    /* get linked */
    pLast->next = temp;
  }

  return aRecordPointer;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a very inefficient method of tail-insertion, taking *O(n)* time.  You can achieve *O(1)* time if you also keep a pointer to the tail element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that aRecordPointer is a pointer to the last Node, modify your code as below:

```
struct recordNode* createRecord(char* name, char* event, float time) 
{ 
  temp = (struct recordNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct recordNode));
  strcpy(temp->name, name);
  strcpy(temp->event, event);
  temp->time = time;

  //I have added this line as well.
  temp->next = NULL;

  /* link up */
  if (aRecordPointer == NULL) 
  {
     aRecordPointer = temp;
  } 
  else 
  {
     aRecordPointer->next = temp;
     aRecordPointer = temp;
  }
  return aRecordPointer;
}
```

Also note that you should always have a pointer to Head (First Node) in order to traverse the linked list later.

Comment: your solution only can print 2 record

Comment: @hkvega: Your question is very incomplete. You need to tell us what is aRecordPointer, where is 'temp' variable defined and how you are trying to print the linked list. I have only tried to fix the part of the code that you produced. There might be other problems as well. Edit your question to include full code.

Comment: @hkvega: Your printing code is still not there. Furthermore, how are you keeping track of Head of linked list?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void Traverse();

struct recordNode {
  char name[256];  
  char event[128];  
  float time;
  struct recordNode* next;
};

struct recordNode* temp;
struct recordNode* aRecordPointer = NULL;

struct recordNode* createRecord(char* name, char* event, float time) { 

  struct recordNode * ToTraverseTheLinkedList;
  temp = (struct recordNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct recordNode));
  strcpy(temp->name, name);
  strcpy(temp->event, event);
  temp->time = time;
  temp->next = NULL;

  /* link up */
  if (aRecordPointer == NULL) {
     aRecordPointer = temp;
     //temp->next = NULL;
  }     
    else
    {
    ToTraverseTheLinkedList = aRecordPointer;
    while(ToTraverseTheLinkedList->next != NULL)
        {
             ToTraverseTheLinkedList =  ToTraverseTheLinkedList ->next;

        }
    ToTraverseTheLinkedList->next = temp;
    }
  return  aRecordPointer;

}

int main() {

  createRecord("1abc", "abc", 12.25);
  //Traverse();
  createRecord("2abc", "abc", 25.98);
  createRecord("3abc", "abc", 52.60);  
        Traverse();
}

void Traverse()
{
struct recordNode * temp;
temp = aRecordPointer;
while(temp != NULL)
{
printf("%s\n",temp->name);
printf("%s\n",temp->event);
printf("%f\n",temp->time);
temp = temp->next;
}
}
```

Comment: this should be able to solve your problem...I have added an extra traverse function to check and print the contents of your linked list...

Comment: use *Code Sample* when you want to add source code. The `{}` button or `Ctrl + K` the selected text.